# Apple TV (4th gen) - ability to prevent episodes from playing consecutively?

Tags: appletv, netflix

I've upgraded from 3rd gen Apple TVs to the latest 4th gen model, and I've noticed that almost all apps now play episodes back-to-back until they are manually stopped—"Computers" does this, "Netflix," "Disney Junior" and others all seem to follow this model.

Is there a way to disable this—globally would be best, or at least for the aforementioned three apps? Our young children were used to watching one episode of a show, then being done with TV when the episode ended. Now it automatically starts up a second episode and they understandably want to keep watching.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with any default app.

As a workaround, Plex allows this if you set up a playlist (Play Queue) for each item and play the queue rather than choosing an individual video from a collection.

Comment: What an unfortunate change. For local content, you shouldn't need Plex to make lots of little playlists with one item apiece, but that's not really a satisfying answer.